# How to share score on Facebook status from Cocos2D-x App for BB Playbook/Z10?

Tags: c++, facebook, cocos2d-x, blackberry-playbook

My question is simple, but I can't find anything helpful, I hope you guys can help me.

In my game, when the player finish the game, there is a scene in my cocos2d-x game that ask for a name to enter in the score table. This scene has a Facebook button (that doesn't do any action right now) that is supposed to pop up a dialog and share the score on his wall with a simple message like "I just scored 7654296 points in "this game". ".

I can't find any example, the Facebook API is just for android and iOS. Is there any C++ native API that I can use?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest *native* C++ API is the stream output.

The C++ language has no knowledge of web pages, cookie files or graphics.

You'll need to search the web for platform specific API.